# sort pandas string column by first few characters of string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe which has uuids attached with some other file info:

```
ff8738hjgdj792__somevar1.txt
9jldh93k4043ik__some3var.txt
```

I would like to sort the dataframe based on the first uuid field (till the double underscores) and ignore the other `attached string` to sort?

At the moment I do:

```
df.sort_values(by='df_column_name')
```

but this is not yielding the desired result because pd is taking the entire string into account.

How do I go about achieving this with pandas?

Comment: Create a new column with `.str.split('__')[0]` ?

Comment: @RichieV that sounds pretty ugly :(

Answer (score 1):

Pandas 1.1.0+ has parameter `key`. Use it to sort as regular python `sort`

Sample `df`:

```
                           col1
0  ff8738hjgdj792__somevar1.txt
1  9jldh93k4043ik__some3var.txt

df['col1'].sort_values(key=lambda x: x.str.split('__').str[0])

Out[809]:
1    9jldh93k4043ik__some3var.txt
0    ff8738hjgdj792__somevar1.txt
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Or

```
df_final = df.sort_values(by='col1',key=lambda x: x.str.split('__').str[0])

Out[812]:
                           col1
1  9jldh93k4043ik__some3var.txt
0  ff8738hjgdj792__somevar1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using pandas, I suggest adding pandasql. It makes it easy to accomplish what you're looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

# Recreating the data you provided
df = pd.DataFrame(['ff8738hjgdj792__somevar1.txt', '9jldh93k4043ik__some3var.txt'], columns = ['something']) 

# Selecting and sorting by the the the length of the substring you're looking for
df_res = ps.sqldf("""
    select something 
    from df 
    order by substr(something, 0, length('ff8738hjgdj792')) """, locals())


print(df_res)
```

Returns

```
                      something
0  9jldh93k4043ik__some3var.txt
1  ff8738hjgdj792__somevar1.txt
```